# VBA Code Not Working after Error Check

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the below to check values are not exceeded in ranges B14 & E21.  If the values in either of these ranges are exceeded, then a msgbox should appear to advise the user of the error.

I have error checked the code and it is not highlighting any errors, but when I go to run it nothing is happening.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TooManyHolidays()

Dim msg As String
Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult

If Sheets("Request Form").Range("B14") < 26 And Sheets("Request Form").Range("E21") < 10 Then
    NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck
ElseIf Sheets("Request Form").Range("B14") >= 26 Then
    msg = (" You Dont Have Enough Holiday ")
    Ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbNo Then
        Sheets("Request Form").Select
        Range("Employee3").ClearContents
        Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Quit
    End If
    If Ans = vbYes Then
        Sheets("Request Form").Select
        Range("Employee3").ClearContents
        Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
        Range("Employee3") = Application.Username
    ElseIf Sheets("Request Form").Range("E21") >= 10 Then
        msg = (" You Cant Book More Than 10 Or More Days In One Request ")
        Ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
        If Ans = vbNo Then
            Sheets("Request Form").Select
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.Quit
        End If
        If Ans = vbYes Then
            Sheets("Request Form").Select
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Range("Employee3") = Application.Username
        End If
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck` ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: what values did you enter in `Range("B14")` and in `Range("E21")` that nothing happened ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below will give you what you wanted (even though I don't know what is `NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck`), or what are you doing if both Range("B14") and Range("E21") are inside the permitted values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TooManyHolidays()

Dim msg As String
Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult

With Sheets("Request Form")

    If .Range("B14") < 26 And .Range("E21") < 10 Then
        NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck '<-- don't know what this does ?
    ElseIf .Range("B14") >= 26 Then
        msg = (" You Dont Have Enough Holiday ")
        Ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
        If Ans = vbNo Then
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.Quit
        End If
        If Ans = vbYes Then
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName
        End If            
    ElseIf .Range("E21") >= 10 Then '<-- this should be directly below "If .Range("B14") < 26 And .Range("E21") < 10 Then"
        msg = (" You Cant Book More Than 10 Or More Days In One Request ")
        Ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
        If Ans = vbNo Then
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.Quit
        End If
        If Ans = vbYes Then
            Range("Employee3").ClearContents
            Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
            Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName
        End If
    End If

End With

End Sub
```